# mysql - fetching arrow and setting variable to certain row

Tags: mysql

i can't figure out why $points comes back without a value

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `username` WHERE `password` = '$pword' AND `username` = '$uname'");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$points = $rows[points];
```

Comment: may be the first row has the points value blank

Comment: Check whether the column name is same as the one you gave here.. Also please turn on error reporting to check if there is any error.. Make sure your query runs and fetches records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use  `SELECT points FROM`username`WHERE`password`= '$pword' AND`username`= '$uname'` and check $pword and $nname values passing values or not

```
$points = $rows['points'];
```